# Does Vertex Model Registry cost anything to use?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I can't tell if I will be charged to use Model Registry on Vertex AI. Will it cost anything?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

From the pricing page:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/pricing#modelregistry

The Vertex AI Model Registry is a central repository which tracks and lists your models and model versions. You can import models into Vertex AI and they appear in the Vertex AI Model Registry. There is no cost associated with having your models in the Vertex AI Model Registry. Cost is only incurred when you deploy the model to an endpoint or perform a batch prediction on the model. This cost is determined by the type of model you are deploying.